# Add seconds to sematic ui calendar

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui, ui-calendar

I am using the semantic ui calendar in my emberjs app.

`Here's a a jsbin of how it looks`: [semantic ui calendar](https://jsbin.com/ruqakehefa/1/edit?html,js,output)

The only thing missing is the ability to pick seconds.
You can pick the hours and minutes, but not the seconds.

Can anyone please provide some info on how can I do that?

I'll be willing to use a different component only if its impossible with semantic-ui calendar.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by a quick peek at the [source](https://github.com/mdehoog/Semantic-UI-Calendar/blob/master/src/definitions/modules/calendar.js) where there is no mention of seconds or any way to handle them, it doesn't look like this is something that the library supports. As it is an open source project, you could contribute this, modify the library, or submit an issue in the repository to have the feature added.